Telepresence not able to hit api from job container
I have installed telepresence in service container and in that service container i have checked that it is woring fine perfectly hitting api but when running job in gitlab i have provided this service container as service in my job container in gitlab-ci jobs at that time i try to hit the same api then the api fails and saying that the host which i was hitting in service container that host is not present in job container
i have read that the service container and job container share same network then why this is happening ?
i want to hit the same api from the job container that i am hitting in service container via telepresence
